# Search with multiple tables & ORDER BY php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I have a script i want to search multiple tables how can i do that.

> **Also add ORDER BY function in Mysql query **
>   help is appreciated.

```
 if(isset($_GET["search"]))  
                 {  
                      $condition = '';  
                      //$query = explode(" ", $_GET["search"]);
                      $query = explode(" ", $_GET["search"]);

                      foreach($query as $text)  
                      {  
                           $condition .= "title LIKE +'%".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $text)."%' OR ";  
                      }  
                      $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);  
                      $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE " . $condition;  
                      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_query);  
                      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                      {  
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                           {  
                                echo '<tr><td>'.$row["title"].'</td></tr>';  
                           }  
                      }  
                      else  
                      {  
                           echo '<label>Data not Found</label>';  
                      }  
                 }
```

Comment: use a `union` query, or query each table separately.

Comment: can u write down the syntax @MarcB

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (    

(SELECT title FROM countries WHERE title LIKE '%mystring%')
    UNION
    (SELECT title FROM locations WHERE title LIKE '%mystring%')

) ta
```

That's the sql, but would need to point out the drawbacks of using union as a search tool.

a) The longer the tables get the longer the search will get, you can add in Limits on each query and then on the union as a whole - but it's not a winner.

b) The table columns have to match up so you'll need perhaps to do myID as ID, then you will need an extra column to say which each is (0=country, 1= location)

c) I guess you are trying to do a site search of sorts, in which case there isn't a relevance in this instance.

Hence I would use something like http://sphinxsearch.com/ bit tricky to get started, but a really quick search engine. If you have a large site. Otherwise look into mysql full text searches which also have relevence and are built in so easier to get started with.

Comment: i use UNION and UNION ALL but i get some error in my query @http://stackoverflow.com/users/4054808/richard-housham

Comment: I've made a slight edit placing a 'SELECT * FROM ( query) ta' around the table. Might solve your problem. To be honest I would make the query. Echo it out. Copy paste into your phpMyAdmin (or whatever) and then debug from there.